# cannot pull from repo due to unsaved .vs changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am trying to pull from a repo, but I cannot because of the ".vs" folder which is not in the repo already.

I am getting the error "Cannot pull because of unsaved changes"

I tried adding it to .gitignore, which is in the base directory and it contains

```
.vs
```

however, the problem persists. How do I fix this?

Comment: Post the output of git status